# Why is the input altered when the function runs on a different declared variable?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, the operatorSequence function should run using the variable "input" and *not* "inputArray", however the inputArray ("a") is altered when the function is run.

What is causing this issue, and how can it be fixed so that the inputArray isn't changed?

```js
//factorial in maths
function factorial(input) {
  if (input == 0) return 1;
  if (input > 0) return input * factorial(input - 1);
}
//slices an index from an array
function sliceIndex(array, index) {
  let temp = array.slice(0, index);
  temp.push.apply(temp, array.slice(index + 1));
  return temp;
}

//operator sequence
function operatorSequence(inputArray, operatorArray, det) {
  //the function should run on the "input" variable
  let input = inputArray;
  //det determines bracket position
  //according to the bracket position, two input indices are merged into one, and an operator is deleted
  while(operatorArray.length > 0) {
    let temp1 = factorial(operatorArray.length - 1);
    let temp2 = Math.floor(det / temp1);
    input[temp2] = operatorArray[temp2](input[temp2], input[temp2 + 1]);
    operatorArray = sliceIndex(operatorArray, temp2);
    input = sliceIndex(input, temp2 + 1);
    det -= temp1 * temp2;
  }
  return input[0];
}

const a = [1, 8, 3, 4];
let b = [(a, b) => a + b, (a, b) => a - b, (a, b) => a * b];
console.log(operatorSequence(a, b, 0));
console.log(a);
//24
//[9, 8, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `let input = inputArray;` does not create a copy. `let input = inputArray.slice();` does.

Comment: Also, avoid using variables with the same name as the function containing them, like in `let b = [(a, b) => a + b, (a, b) => a - b, (a, b) => a * b];`.

Comment: @Xufox, the last is an array of functions. the names do not matter to the outside used variable names.

Answer (score 1):

```
let input = inputArray;
```

The assignment of an array to another variable does not produce a new array with values. Instead it uses the same object reference to the original array.

Later, you assign values

```
input[temp2] = operatorArray[temp2](input[temp2], input[temp2 + 1]);
```

to the array `input` as `inputArray` as the original array `a`.

You could work with a shallow copy of the array by using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
let input = inputArray.slice();
```